# Lock.java and LockSupport.java: what purpose we have LockSupport?

Tags: java, multithreading, locks

I have used basic `object.wait()` , `object.notify() , object.notifyAll()` in multi-threaded programming.

I know we have the package `java.util.concurrent` and it has `java.util.concurrent.locks` package. Specifically in `java.util.concurrent.locks` we have : `Condition`, `Lock` and `LockSupport` (among others).

I read online about this package, and understood basics of `Lock` and `Condition`. However, I didn't understand `LockSupport`. I did search to understand `LockSupport` , however didn't find anything relevant which can help me understand what it is used for. I have seen that in `LockSupport` we have methods like `park()` , `unPark()` etc. However, I didn't get what is the purpose of `LockSupport`, it seems to be doing more or less same like `Lock`?

Can anyone please help me understand why we have `LockSupport` and what it does that `Lock` don't do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a helper class with very low level concurrency mechanisms that are used by the other classes. Unless you want to write your own higher level concurrency structures, you probably won't use it.

There are other helper classes like `java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer`, which provide other mechanisms (e.g. wait queues in case of `AQS`) to the classes that *you* are more likely to use, like `ReentrantLock` and so on.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So does it mean that we should use LockSupport only if we are creating a new DataStructure which need synchronization / thread safe? I read javadoc of this, it has multiple concepts within like : `permit`, `Semaphore` etc. Can you elaborate a bit more for understanding, please?

Comment: @CuriousMind not data structure, but your own concurrency mechanism if you were to come up with a specific kind of lock or something. Otherwise there's no reason to need the kind of low level access that `LockSupport` provides.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. So it means that if we want to implement `our own way of synchronization` (not necessarily using Locks, Synchronized keyword etc.) then we can create a new implementation (a Class) which internally would use LockSupport. And `LockSupport` internally uses `sun.misc.Unsafe` to do so. Is this correct conclusion?

Comment: @CuriousMind if you want to create a `CuriousMindLock` class or a `CuriousMindConcurrentQueue`, then you might find use from `LockSupport`, otherwise you'll probably never use that class.